# GWT Wrong Date in DataGrid under Internet Explorer

Tags: java, javascript, json, internet-explorer, gwt

I have issue with date under Internet Explorer. In my app I have below code and it is working fine under FF/Chrome. When it is loaded under IE the date is very strange Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 GMT+200 1970
The response from server is valid one, but when it is passed to TextCell this wrong date format is shown. I have used DateCell instead of TextCell the result is the same.
Thank you!

```
@UiField(provided = true)
final AbstractCellTable<Object> table = new DataGrid<Object>(
        new ProvidesKey<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object getKey(Object item) {
                return item.getStatus();
            }
        });

Column<Object, ?> column;        

table.addColumn(column = new Column<Object, String>(new TextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Object object) {
            DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss y");
            String formatedDate = format.format(object.getModified());
            return formatedDate;
        }
    }, "Modified on");
```

If app is in Dev Mode the date is fine!?

EDIT:

I found the problem: text Object is my json String. It is with correct date, but after it pass two lines below the date is wrong!

```
 AutoBean<RestResult> bean = AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, RestResult.class, text);
 RestResult result = bean.as();
```

Comment: As a side note, make DateTimeFormat a static class variable. Currently you create it every time every row is updated, but it is always the same. Or use a DateCell.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I will do it.

Comment: Try to use a PredefinedFormat in .getFormat(). Is the result the same?

Comment: I am trying and let you now. It takes a time to apply a new change. Thanks again